# How to use Pattern and Matcher?

Tags: java, regex

I have two simple questions about `Pattern`.

First one is reading the given name(s) and surname. I need to tell whether they contain numbers or punctuation characters. If not, it's a valid name. Whatever I input, the output is

> This is not a valid name.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter: ");
String name = input.next();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
boolean n = m.matches();

if (n == true) {
   System.out.println(name);
}
else {
   System.out.println("This is not a valid name.");
}
```

---

The second question: I read a list of salary amounts that start with a dollar sign `$` and followed by a non-negative number, and save the valid salaries into  an array. My program can output an array, but it can't distinguish `$`.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter Salary: ");
String salary = sc.nextLine();

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("($+)(\\d)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(salary);
String[] slArray=pattern.split(salary);
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(slArray));
```

Comment: You should generally ask one question at a time. Here you've clearly got two very independent questions. I suggest you [edit] it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't even use a formal matcher for these simple use cases.  Java's `String#matches()` method can just as easily handle this.  To check for a valid name using your rules, you could try this:

```
String name = input.next();
if (name.matches("[A-Za-z]+")) {
     System.out.println(name);
}
else {
    System.out.println("This is not a valid name.");
}
```

And to check salary amounts, you could use:

```
String salary = sc.nextLine();
if (salary.matches("\\$\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?")) {
    System.out.println("Salary is valid.");
}
```

A note on the second pattern `\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?`, we need to escape dollar sign, because it is a regex metacharacter.  Also, I did not use `^` and `$` anchors in any of the two patterns, because `String#matches()` by default applies the pattern to the entire string.

**Edit:**

If you have multiple currency amounts in a given line, then split by whitespace to get an array of currency strings:

```
String input = "$23 $24.50 $25.10";
String[] currencies = input.split("\\s+");
```

Then, use the above matching logic to check each entry.

Comment: But I need to input a string. For example, '$22 $23 $24 25', and output should be like this [$22, $23, $24]. I use` \$\d+(?:\.\d+)?`, the output is null, like this[ ].

Comment: @ziyuzhang Then split your input by space.  Check my updated answer.

Comment: That makes sense! Thx : )

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

Your regex pattern is wrong. You are missing the symbol to repeat the pattern.

Currently you have `[A-Za-z]` which matches **only one** letter. You can repeat using

- `*` - 0 to infinite repetitions
- `?` - 0 to 1 repetitions
- `+` - 1 to infinite repetitions
- `{x, y}` - x to y repetitions

So you probably wanted a pattern like `[A-Za-z]+`. You can use sites like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to test your regex patterns (it also explains the pattern in detail). See [regex101/n6OZGp](https://regex101.com/r/n6OZGp/1) for an example of your pattern.

[Here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) is a tutorial on the regex repetition symbols.

---

For the second problem you need to know that `$` is a special symbol in regex. It stands for the end of a line. If you want to match the `$` symbol instead you need to **escape** it by adding a backslash:

```
"\\$\\d+"
```

Note that you need to add two backslashes because the backslash itself has a special meaning in Java. So you first need to escape the backslash using a backslash so that the string itself contains a backslash:

```
\$\d+
```

which then is passed to the regex engine. The same if you want to match a `+` sign, you need to escape it.

---

### Notes

If you just want to check a given `String` against a pattern you can use the `String#matches` method:

```
String name = "John";
if (name.matches("[A-Za-z]+")) {
    // Do something
}
```

Also note that there are [shorthand character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) like `\w` (word character) which is short for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Code like

```
if (n == true) { ... }
```

can be simplified to just

```
if (n) { ... }
```

Because `n` already is a `boolean`, you don't need to test it against `true` anymore.

To parse currency values you should consider using already given methods like

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
Number num = format.parse("$5.34");
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) of the class for examples.

Comment: I don't understand why you suggested the pattern `[a-Z-a-z]+`.  Can you explain this?  And I also don't understand `(\\$+)(\\d)`.  Why would a currency have more than one dollar sign?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That was a typo, corrected. Let me know if anything is unclear. The dollar-thing was used like this by OP, removed it too.

Comment: "\\$\\d+"  I use this, but it doesn't work. The output is null, like this "[ ]".

Comment: btw, I need to input a string. For example,  '$22 $23 $24 25', and output should be like this [$22, $23, $24]. Please tell me how to program this. T_T

Comment: @ziyuzhang I would suggest to ask a new question. StackOverflow is not meant for "discussion". Of course you can link to this question if the new one is related.